# What is the name of the groove down the middle of an anther?

Tags: botany, terminology, plant-anatomy

I thought it had a name along the lines of interlocular groove, but I haven't been able to find that term anywhere.

Comment: You probably mean the filament. [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9zXCc.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9zXCc.png)

Comment: There are two longitudinal ridges in a typical anther. An anther has two lobes each with two pollen sacs/thecae. So there is a groove both between the two lobes and also between the two thecae in one lobe. Having a look at the transverse section would help. Although I don't know what they are called, it would be better if you specify which of the two ridges you are refering to.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is the **connective**. Anthers are usually two-lobed and connected by a band of sterile tissue that also connects the anther with the filament - therefore the name, I guess (see Wikipedia article for [stamen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stamen)). It says

> Most commonly anthers are two-lobed and are attached to the filament either at the base or in the middle area of the anther. The sterile tissue between the lobes is called the connective.

Each anther lobe usually consists of two pollen sacs (see Wikipedia article for [microsporangia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsporangia)). It says:

> Each anther lobe develops two pollen sacs. Thus, a two-lobed anther develops four pollen sacs situated at four corners of the anther.

And further (accentuation by me)

> The cells of endothecium possess fibrous thickenings. They remain thin-walled and constitute stomium (line of dehiscence) in the **shallow groove** in between the two microsporangia of the anther lobe.

This groove frequently is called by its orientation, i.e. **longitudinal groove**, even though I do not think this really is a well-defined technical term (but do a quick Google search for `"longitudinal groove" anther` and you will find several biology books using the term, e.g. [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=POA_DAAAQBAJ&pg=SA2-PA3&lpg=SA2-PA3&dq=%22longitudinal+groove%22+anther&source=bl&ots=UyAdgvWJiL&sig=VytMcOyI1rIyZJd90O12kGg76Cs&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIpcGGw7XRAhWEjSwKHVKtB0IQ6AEIOjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22longitudinal%20groove%22%20anther&f=false)).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're talking either about the *connective* that separates two lobes of the anther,  or the *longitudinal groove* that I think separates the two theca making it *dithecous*.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then either delete or [edit] your answer accordingly. It isn't clear that this adds anything to the existing answer. In addition, answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. Finally, if you include a figure you must document where it came from. Thanks! 